# Using webcam's button in my own program

Tags: c#, webcam

My webcam has a button, with which you take a photo of current frame
when using it's original software what came with it when I bought it.

Is there any way to use that button to take photos in my program.
I would be using C#.

I was thinking of using **Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)** or **avicap32**
for using webcam in my software.

Any help would be appreciated. Where do I start?

EDIT:

I see that you didn't understand me. I need to know if my phisycal camera button is pressed.
I am using DigiMicro 1.3 camera (Manufacturer is **DNT**), which isn't really a webcam but a USB microscope, but
it behaves like a webcam.

Comment: Are you asking how to take a photo using WIA, or how to know when the physical button on your webcam has been pressed? If the latter, we need to know which webcam you have. I don't think there's a standard interface for that sort of thing.

Comment: The later. I need to know how do I know if the button on my camera is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the camera actually require that the software be running when you press the button? I know some webcams implement this feature at the driver level. If that's the case, I don't think there's much you can do without interacting directly with the USB port, which would be incredibly difficult and likely not worth the trouble. I can't find any technical documentation on the vendor's website with that kind of information.

The "MicroCapture" software doesn't come with any DLLs that have exported functions, so P/Invoking doesn't appear to be an option. Unfortunately, I can't get the driver installed, so I can't check if it comes with any P/Invoke-able DLLs.

Sorry, but since there's no standard interface for that kind of functionality and the vendor doesn't provide any specific information on it, I don't think this is possible. I would suggest contacting DNT directly about it. They may have some component that will do what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I will contact DNT for further info on this.

Comment: @ttkalec How did this end? Did you contact DNT? What was the outcome? I use Linux and just tested 2 webcams. When pressing the button, a keyboard event is available, like with media keyboards which is simplest to deal with. For advanced usages, (e.g. several devices) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612210/grab-signal-from-webcam-button and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398660/detecting-usb-camera-button-event .

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon It was almost 10 years ago :) In the end I didn't manage to get the hardware button to work, instead I devised a workaround which was good enough for the client at the time.

Comment: @ttkalec Okay. I wrote this as much to provide an example of updated answer as to know how things ended for you. Any comparison between solutions 10 years apart is risky, yet it's interesting that Linux current approach seemed much simpler in this case, as it's very easy to get keyboard events in most programming environments.

Answer (score 0):

This Coding4Fun post guides you through pretty much everything you need to do to get started using WIA, including adding the reference to a project, displaying the select a device dialog, and of course actually taking the picture :P.

[Coding4Fun - Look at me! Windows Image Acquisition](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912546.aspx)

Comment: In this threat I'm particulary interested in using a physical button on my camera for taking photos, not using my camera in C# app. But thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the [DirectShow.NET library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). It has great functionality for capturing images/videos off connected devices. It also comes with several samples to get you started quickly.

Comment: In this thread I'm asking on how to use a physical button on my camera, not using the camera in my C# project. Tnx anyway ;)