# grab signal from webcam button

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a webcam and it has button. In Windows, when I push that button it grabs image snapshot. But now I am on linux and I am using VLC to view video from my usb webcam "/dev/video0". I would like to use python to get signal from that button once pushed - I mean just to get this signal (no grab snapshot automatically). 
I tried to google it, but no luck. I don't want to use opencv or gstreamer to get video into new window, I just need to grab signal when button on webcam is pushed. Any idea how to get this signal please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `python-evdev` you can capture events triggered by input devices like mouse, keyboard,..., and also webcams

> evdev is a Linux-only generic protocol that the kernel uses to forward
>   information and events about input devices to userspace. It's not just
>   for mice and keyboards but any device that has any sort of axis, key
>   or button, including things like webcams and remote controls. Each
>   device is represented as a device node in the form of
>   /dev/input/event0, with the trailing number increasing as you add more
>   devices. The node numbers are re-used after you unplug a device, so
>   don't hardcode the device node into a script. The device nodes are
>   also only readable by root, thus you need to run any debugging tools
>   as root too.

http://who-t.blogspot.de/2016/09/understanding-evdev.html

the button of the webcam also has an event assigned, you have to find in which `/dev/input/` folder

run the following code from http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html  to get the `/dev/input` path of your webcam :

**Listing accessible event devices**

```
 import evdev

 devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
 for device in devices:
     print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys)
```